# Get search result count in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

How to get Search result count and keyword in `result.phtml` in magento2.

I have overriden the `Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/result.phtml` file.

I need to show the count returned from the search result as well as the key searched here.

Is that possible to get it. Please anyone suggest on this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please upload your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get  Search result count `$block->getResultCount()`

and  use keyword for get `$this->helper('Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data')->getEscapedQueryText()`

Comment: hi @Amit, got count but keyword is not returned

Comment: My mistake, i don't paste proper class name

Comment: ok, thanks it worked, could you check the Terms and condition issue?

Answer (score 3):

To get **Search Result count** :

```
$resultCount = $block->getResultCount();
```

To get **Search Keyword** :

```
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Search\Helper\Data');
$searchKeyword = $helper->getEscapedQueryText();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result` this block in your custom module. Then you can use this below code :

For search keyword :

```
$this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText()
```

OR

```
$this->helper('Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data')->getEscapedQueryText()
```

For count :

```
$block->getResultCount()
```